# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex

When I press Add to add information, Update to edit information, Delete to delete information, it will show the Error as below. I tried to find many places but couldn't fix it successfully. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me fix my code. Thanks for the answer in advance.

```
vue-loading.min.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at Proxy.focusIn (vue-loading.min.js:1:1)
    at vi._handleFocusin (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at HTMLDocument.i (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at Proxy.focusIn (vue-loading.min.js:1:1)
    at vi._handleFocusin (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at HTMLDocument.i (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
    at Proxy.focusIn (vue-loading.min.js:1:1)
    at vi._handleFocusin (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1)
```

This is the Shool.vue page code.

```
<template>
  <div id="school">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="p-3 bg-success bg-gradient text-white rounded-4">
        บันทึกข้อมูลสถานศึกษา
      </div>
      <!-- The Modal School -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="MSchool"
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        data-bs-keyboard="false"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="MSchool"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 fw-bold" id="MSchool">
                {{
                  modalStatus === 1
                    ? "เพิ่มข้อมูลสถานศึกษา"
                    : "แก้ไขหรือลบข้อมูลสถานศึกษา"
                }}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
                @click="resetInputSchool()"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form @submit.prevent="CRUDSchool()">
                <div class="row align-items-center g-3">
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">เลือกจังหวัด :</label>
                    <select
                      class="form-select"
                      aria-label="Default select example"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.pro_id"
                      required
                    >
                      <option value="" selected disabled>
                        --- เลือกจังหวัด ---
                      </option>
                      <option
                        v-for="item in getProvince"
                        :key="item.pro_code"
                        :value="`${item.pro_code}`"
                      >
                        {{ item.pro_name }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">เลือกอำเภอ :</label>
                    <select
                      class="form-select"
                      aria-label="Default select example"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.dis_id"
                      required
                    >
                      <option value="" selected disabled>
                        --- เลือกอำเภอ ---
                      </option>
                      <option
                        v-for="item in filteredDistricts"
                        :key="item.dis_id"
                        :value="`${item.dis_id}`"
                      >
                        {{ item.dis_name }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">เลือกตำบล :</label>
                    <select
                      class="form-select"
                      aria-label="Default select example"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.loc_id"
                      required
                    >
                      <option value="" selected disabled>
                        --- เลือกตำบล ---
                      </option>
                      <option
                        v-for="item in filteredLocality"
                        :key="item.loc_id"
                        :value="`${item.loc_id}`"
                      >
                        {{ item.loc_name }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center g-3 mt-1">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">ชื่อสถานศึกษา :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="ชื่อสถานศึกษา"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.sch_name"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">ที่อยู่สถานศึกษา :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="ที่อยู่สถานศึกษา ตัวอย่างเช่น (162 ม.2)"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.sch_homeid"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center g-3 mt-1">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">ถนน :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="ถนน"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.sch_road"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                    <label class="form-label fw-bold">รหัสไปรษณีย์ :</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="รหัสไปรษณีย์"
                      v-model="getCRUDSchool.sch_postcode"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center g-3 mt-1">
                  <div class="col-md-auto col-12">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      :class="[
                        'btn',
                        modalStatus === 1 ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-success',
                      ]"
                      :id="[modalStatus === 1 ? 'Add' : 'Update']"
                      @click="Checkclick"
                    >
                      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'plus']" />
                      {{
                        modalStatus === 1 ? "เพิ่มข้อมูล" : "บันทึกข้อมูล"
                      }}</button
                    >&nbsp;<button
                      v-if="this.modalStatus === 2"
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-danger"
                      @click="D_School()"
                    >
                      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'minus']" />
                      ลบข้อมูล</button
                    >&nbsp;<button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      class="btn btn-secondary"
                      @click="resetInputSchool()"
                    >
                      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'power-off']" />
                      ปิดหน้านี้
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-centers g-3 mt-1">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <!-- ฺButton Show Model School -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal()">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'plus']" />
            เพิ่มข้อมูลสถานศึกษา
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <!-- ฺButton Export Excel -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="onExport()">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'file-excel']" />
            Export Excel
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Data Table -->
      <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
        <fieldset class="border rounded-3 p-3">
          <legend class="float-none w-auto px-3 fw-bold">
            รายการข้อมูลสถานศึกษา
          </legend>
          <table class="table table-hover text-center myschool" id="myschool">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">รหัสสถานศึกษา</th>
                <th scope="col">ชื่อสถานศึกษา</th>
                <th scope="col">ที่อยู่สถานศึกษา</th>
                <th scope="col">ถนน</th>
                <th scope="col">รหัสไปรษณีย์</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr
                @click="selected_tr(item)"
                v-for="(item, index) in getSchool"
                :key="item.sch_th_id"
                role="button"
              >
                <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ item.sch_th_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.sch_th_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.sch_th_addr }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.sch_th_road }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.sch_th_postcode }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      modalStatus: null,
      selected_school_Province: "",
      selected_school_District: "",
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch("getData_gen/R_School");
  },
  computed: {
    filteredDistricts() {
      return this.getDistrict.filter(
        (item) => item.pro_id === this.getCRUDSchool.pro_id
      );
    },
    filteredLocality() {
      return this.getLocality.filter(
        (item) =>
          item.pro_id === this.getCRUDSchool.pro_id &&
          item.dis_id === this.getCRUDSchool.dis_id
      );
    },
    ...mapGetters({
      getProvince: "getData_gen/_getDataProvince",
      getLocality: "getData_gen/_getDataLocality",
      getDistrict: "getData_gen/_getDataDistrict",
      getSchool: "getData_gen/_getDataSchool",
      getCRUDSchool: "getData_gen/_getCRUDSchool",
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    async showModal() {
      this.modalStatus = 1;
      await $("#MSchool").modal("show");
    },
    async selected_tr(payload) {
      this.modalStatus = 2;
      const selectedProvince = this.getProvince.find(
        (province) =>
          province.pro_name.trim() === payload.sch_th_province.trim()
      );
      const selectedDistrict = this.getDistrict.find(
        (district) =>
          district.dis_name.trim() === payload.sch_th_district.trim()
      );
      const selectedLocality = this.getLocality.find(
        (locality) =>
          locality.loc_name.trim() === payload.sch_th_locality.trim()
      );
      console.log(selectedProvince.pro_code);
      console.log(selectedDistrict.dis_id);
      console.log(selectedLocality.loc_id);
      this.getCRUDSchool.pro_id = selectedProvince.pro_code;
      this.getCRUDSchool.dis_id = selectedDistrict.dis_id;
      this.getCRUDSchool.loc_id = selectedLocality.loc_id;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_th_id = payload.sch_th_id;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_name = payload.sch_th_name;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_homeid = payload.sch_th_homeid;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_road = payload.sch_th_road;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_postcode = payload.sch_th_postcode;
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_th_addr = payload.sch_th_addr;
      $("#MSchool").modal("show");
    },
    resetInputSchool() {
      this.getCRUDSchool.pro_id = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.dis_id = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.loc_id = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_name = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_homeid = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_road = "";
      this.getCRUDSchool.sch_postcode = "";
    },
    Checkclick(e) {
      this.getCRUDSchool.status = e.target.id;
    },
    async CRUDSchool() {
      await this.$store.dispatch("getData_gen/CRUDSchool", true);
      $("#MSchool").modal("hide");
      this.resetInputSchool();
    },
    async D_School() {
      let text_html = `
        <small>
            <b>รหัส</b> <u>${this.getCRUDSchool.sch_th_id}</u> <br>
            <b>ชื่อสถาบัน</b> <u>${this.getCRUDSchool.sch_name}</u> <br>
            <b>ที่อยู่</b> <u>${this.getCRUDSchool.sch_th_addr}</u> <br>
            <b>ถนน</b> <u>${this.getCRUDSchool.sch_road}</u> <br>
            <b>รหัสไปรษณีย์</b> <u>${this.getCRUDSchool.sch_postcode}</u>
        </small>`;
      window.Swal.fire({
        title: "ต้องการลบใช่หรือไม่ ?",
        text: "คุณต้องการลบข้อมูลนี้ใช่หรือไม่!",
        html: text_html,
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#d33",
        cancelButtonColor: "#6c757d",
        confirmButtonText: "ต้องการลบ",
        cancelButtonText: "ยกเลิก",
      }).then(async (result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          this.getCRUDSchool.status = "Delete";
          this.CRUDSchool();
        }
      });
    },
    onExport() {
      const table = $("#myschool").DataTable();
      const data = table.data().toArray();
      const headers = [
        "#",
        "รหัสสถานศึกษา",
        "รหัสสถานศึกษา",
        "ที่อยู่สถานศึกษา",
        "ถนน",
        "รหัสไปรษณีย์",
      ];
      data.unshift(headers);
      const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
      const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      const columnWidths = [
        { wch: 10 },
        { wch: 20 },
        { wch: 45 },
        { wch: 50 },
        { wch: 35 },
        { wch: 10 },
      ];
      ws["!cols"] = columnWidths;
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, "school.xlsx");
    },
  },
  watch: {
    getSchool: {
      async handler() {
        await $("#myschool").DataTable().destroy();
        await $("#myschool").DataTable({
          columnDefs: [
            { className: "dt-center", targets: "_all" },
            { className: "dt-body-left", targets: [2, 3, 4] },
          ],
          responsive: true,
        });
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

This is the getData general.js page code. (Vuex)

```
const state = () => ({
  DataSchool: [],
  CRUDSchool: {
    status: "",
    pro_id: "",
    dis_id: "",
    loc_id: "",
    sch_th_id: "",
    sch_name: "",
    sch_homeid: "",
    sch_th_addr: "",
    sch_road: "",
    sch_postcode: "",
  },
})
const getters = {
  _getDataSchool: (state) => {
    return state.DataSchool;
  },
  _getCRUDSchool: (state) => {
    return state.CRUDSchool;
  },
}
const actions = {
  async CRUDSchool({ state, dispatch }) {
    try {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("CRUDSchool", JSON.stringify(state.CRUDSchool));
      const response = await window.Axios.post(
        `${window.api}exec/CRUDSchool/`,
        formData
      );
      await window.Swal.fire({
        position: "center",
        icon: response.data.type,
        title: response.data.alert,
        text: response.data.text,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500,
      });
      if (response.data.type == "success") await dispatch("R_School");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  async R_School({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await window.Axios.get(
        `${window.api}get/getSchool_inthailand/`
      );
      await commit("R_School", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },}
const mutations = {
  R_School(state, payload) {
    state.DataSchool = payload;
  },
}
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Comment: Switch to the unminified versions of vue-loading.js and bootstrap.bundle.js during debugging. the error is from there, not your actual vuex code.